# TextField hiding under keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a view with 10 textfields in it, when I tap on a textfield keyboard appears, this keyboard hides textfields and I was unable to see textfielld while editing.

I have seen something  in UICatalog which moves corresonding textfield up in the view while editing but unable to follow the code ie which portion of the code is performing this.

Can you please spread some light on this.